# Parameter passing during instance creation - smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

### Homework Question

Is it possible (or even recommended) to pass parameters to a class during initialization? Or even, before that - during instantiation.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
f:=Farm type: #chickens
```

and then during initialization have this do something along the lines of ...

```
myAnimalTracker := AnimalTracker new type
```

From the `AnimalTracker` side of things, I'd like to decide which type of object is created based on the type. In this example, `AnimalTracker` would have several subclasses (`Chickens`, `Pigs`, `Cows`, etc.) - and during the instantiation, I'd like to be able to decide which type of object gets created.

---

It does seem to make more sense to just decide this on the `Farm` side of things (i.e., just instantiate the type of class I want directly, based on the type) but alas, it does not appear the directions are worded this way.

Comment: It would be nice if you rename a title of question to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.

Usually you do something like

```
Farm new initializeWithType: #chicken
```

but you can also shorten that into

```
Farm ofType: #chicken
```

that will eventually do the previous thing (it's essential to have initialization method).

Maybe even some more shortcuts like

```
Farm newWithChikens
```

But I'd recommend you to read [Smalltalk With Style](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/WithStyle/SmalltalkWithStyle.pdf) so you'll be very cool.

Answer (score 1):

The smalltalk way is to take a look in the image how it is done.
Take a look at the implementors (and then senders) of

```
on:
```

You'll notice most of them are defined at the class side.
In Squeak & Pharo, by default the new method (on the class side)
calls initialize on the instance side.